# How to manually download android libraries from dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Download/extract it:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

To use like this:

```
compile files('src/main/java/lib/picasso-2.5.0.jar')
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What do you plan to do for a dependency that has transitive dependencies?

Comment: @CommonsWare 
I would like to use the local libraries to escape the dependency of the repository

Comment: Gradle caches the artifacts loaded from repositories. Once you have loaded them, you will not need to download them again. IMHO, you should be focused on how you can work offline with Android Studio and Gradle, not hacking your build script.

Comment: @CommonsWare 
in the past I saved a project, but after I open the project in the future, the libraries from the repository are no longer listed

Answer (score 2):

You can always find the libraries in the ~/.m2/repository folder on your system.

Under Windows if I remember correctly is under %HOME%.m2 ...

There you can take the JARs and do whatever you want with them.

Comment: where is ~/.m2/repository folder on my system?

Comment: Which OS do you have?

Comment: I am using windows 10